# Missing vav or not in Bamidbar 7:2

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, commentaries, rashi, mesorah-tradition

In parshat Nasso (Bamidbar 7:2), the Torah says
וַיַּקְרִ֙יבוּ֙ נְשִׂיאֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל רָאשֵׁ֖י בֵּ֣ית אֲבֹתָ֑ם הֵ֚ם נְשִׂיאֵ֣י הַמַּטֹּ֔ת הֵ֥ם הָעֹמְדִ֖ים עַל־הַפְּקֻדִֽים׃

On this verse, the Minchat Shai says the following:
המטת. בהעתק הללי המטת ירושלמי המטות ע"כ. ובכל הספרים חסר והוא חד מן ג' חסרים ע"פ המסורת וכן מסרה הרמ"ה ז"ל:

Where can we found this note of the הרמ"ה ז"ל? Any suggestion would be appreciated here.

Comment: ramah is here http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40176&st=&pgnum=57&hilite=

Comment: Are you just seeking the ramah inside (as you say at the end) or is do you want to know anything else about this instance (as your title might indicate)?

Comment: Thanks Double AA, looking for both

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify what exactly you are looking for in the question